# Getting error for PUT 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

The full error: `PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/event/107 500 (Internal Server Error)`.
I am trying to update an existing event within my DB. I have the fetch() setup so it uses the 'PUT' method in my /api/event/${eventid}.

```
      const eventid = arg.event.id;
      console.log(arg.event.id); // ID is logged here
      const eventData = { // Event Data to be sent off is here
        start: arg.event.start.toISOString(),
        end: arg.event.end.toISOString(),
      };
      const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;
      fetch(`/api/event/${eventid}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
        },
        body: encodeFormData(eventData),
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      console.log("Complete");
```

This connects to my route as such:

```
Route::put('/event/{eventid}', [CalendarController::class, 'update']);
```

which also connects to my Controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $eventid)
    {
        dd($request->id);
        $booking = Booking::findOrFail($eventid);
        $booking->start_date = $request->start;
        $booking->end_date = $request->end;
        $booking->save();
        return response()->json($booking);
    }
```

How can I solve the 500 error? There is no obvious reason to me why it would fail to connect. Thanks.

Comment: Switch the position of request and $eventId, it should be `public function update($eventid, Request $request)`. As a side note, I think you can actually inject the `Booking` model by type hinting it in the function parameters as such `public function update(Booking $event, Request $request)` (if you do this don't forget to update `{eventid}` to `{event}` in your routes)

Comment: Switching the position unfortunately doesn't seem to work. I'll see about injection thanks.

Comment: Same thing sadly, I tried your injection solution but it is still returning an Error 500 https://imgur.com/THq4Cg0. Could you confirm this what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: Check your server error.log to see what shows up there;

Comment: Is this Route method is inside api.php? And try     body: JSON.stringify(eventData)

Comment: The server log doesn't seem to directly indicate any issues. Yes it is indeed inside api.php, I've just tried JSON.stringifying it but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you share storate/logs/laravel.log with us?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

```
 const eventid = arg.event.id;
  console.log(arg.event.id); 
  const eventData = { 
    start: arg.event.start.toISOString(),
    end: arg.event.end.toISOString(),
    _method:"PUT" //add method field
  };
  const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;
  fetch(`/api/event/${eventid}`, {
    method: 'POST', // POST method
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
    },
    body: encodeFormData(eventData),
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
  console.log("Complete");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it sent it off as a POST successfully. I can't say for certain this works since I have since switched over to apiResource in an effort to fix this.